# Ruby loop though arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to loop through each item in an array, but the last variable could be an array itself:

```
<% [@in_force_item, @draft_item,@historical_items].compact.each do |item| %>
```

it seems to fail at this line:

```
 <td>
  <%= datetime_to_string item.updated_at %>
 </td>
```

Is it because the historical_items is actually an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can't call `.updated_at` on the array. Just flatten the array before your iteration:

```
<% [@in_force_item, @draft_item,@historical_items].compact.flatten.each do |item| %>
```

Comment: Or just splat it: `[@in_force_item, @draft_item, *@historical_items].each ... `